# To remove a session value from session variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have 4 links in my home page called home.php to add a, b,c,d on clicking on a it will go to a form like this,the below is a.php containing the form to a account

```
      <?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['msgop'];
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="webservice.php">
name<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
password<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

after submitting this form it calls a webservice from the page webservice.php which will give a json return ,it can have the value as

```
  <?php
 $org=$_GET['name'];
 $loc=$_GET['password'];

 $addmachine=array(
'org_name'=>$name,
'loc_name'=>$password,

 );
 $url='webservice url';
    $data="$addmachine";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($addmachine));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $response=  curl_exec($ch);
    echo($response);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json_a=json_decode($response)
    echo $json_a[msg];
    $_SESSION['msgop']=$json_a[msg];
    ?>

    <script>
        var msg=<?php echo $json_a[msg];?>
    if(msg!="Successful")
    {
        location.href='a.php';
    }
     ?>
```

if the value of `$json_a[msg]` is not successfull then the form should not go to webservice.php should stand in the same page ie,a.php and also print the error message (i have did it by storing the value in `$json_a[msg]` to session and display it on a.php,but ) ,if it is successful then it must go to websevice.php and post all entries made in a.php and on the page webservice .php there is link to home page which will go back to the page home.php when we click on a,it will go to a.php but it is showing the value in $json_a[msg] ,how can remove this error message on an attempt to add opaerator again.i have tried unset session ,but no luck
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just empty the value of session using

```
$json_a[msg] = "";
```

Comment: the home.php with link a ,can add have 4 accounts that is a user can add the form 4 times,but each time when i take the form to add account for a ,then it is showing the error message for the last form .

Answer (score 0):

Unset the session variable

```
unset($_SESSION['msgop']);
```